# Why does my VLan have same IP address as underlying physical connection with netplan?

Tags: networking, netplan

I'm trying to configure a vlan on my machine using netplan.

On my router (Synology SRM) I've got two networks defined.

```
Primary Network
Subnet: 192.168.200.1/24
Gateway: 192.168.200.1
Primary DNS: 192.168.200.5
DHCP v4: Enabled
DHCP Start: 192.168.200.154
DHCP End: 192.168.200.254
VLAN ID: Not set / doesn't show the field in the UI.

Network 2
Subnet: 192.168.60.1/24
Gateway: 192.168.60.1
Primary DNS: 192.168.60.1
DHCP v4: Enabled
DHCP Start: 192.168.60.2
DHCP End: 192.168.60.254
VLAN ID: 60
```

My host is running Ubuntu 18.04 with Netplan 0.99.

My /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml looks like this

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      match:
        macaddress: 48:b0:2d:2e:63:b8
      critical: yes
      addresses: [192.168.200.202/24 ]
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.200.5]
      routes:
      - to: 0.0.0.0/0
        via: 192.168.200.1
      mtu: 1500
  vlans:
    vlan60:
      id: 60
      link: eth0
      addresses:
      - 192.168.60.20/24
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.60.1]
      mtu: 1500
```

The output from `ip a` looks like this:

```
greg@jetson01:~$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: dummy0: <BROADCAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 56:94:93:66:7b:09 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 48:b0:2d:2e:63:b8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.200.202/24 brd 192.168.200.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::4ab0:2dff:fe2e:63b8/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: l4tbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f2:54:e5:8e:23:d1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: rndis0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master l4tbr0 state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f2:54:e5:8e:23:d1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: usb0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master l4tbr0 state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f2:54:e5:8e:23:d3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
7: vlan60@eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 48:b0:2d:2e:63:b8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.200.202/24 brd 192.168.200.255 scope global vlan60
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::4ab0:2dff:fe2e:63b8/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
8: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:8e:c3:11:42 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

If you look at #7 in that list, `vlan60@eth0` has `inet 192.168.200.202/24`, the same as `eth0` at #3.

Why does my `vlan60@eth0` interface have the same IP address as the underlying `eth0` interface?

Comment: I reproduced this on 18.04 LTS, 19.04, and 19.10 VMs but it's fixed on 20.04 LTS. It looks like it's because this is a bug

Comment: @DanielT thanks for the effort.  That's a bit of a pain. My hardware is an Nvidia Jetson Nano 2GB which, from what I can see, only has 18.04 available for it. Do you know, is this a bug in netplan, or networkd or somewhere else in the OS? What are my options, if any?

Comment: It's a bug in netplan. I found a 1-line solution and will post an answer

Comment: fyi 18.04 LTS is end of standard support and is offtopic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that netplan.io on Ubuntu 18.04 has a bug where it's accidentally applying the eth0 to the vlan60@eth0. Luckily there's a simple fix. Match the ethernet interface on itself using `name: eth0`:

```yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      match:
        name: eth0 # Work around for eth0's IP overwriting vlan60's IP
        macaddress: 48:b0:2d:2e:63:b8
      critical: yes
      addresses: [192.168.200.202/24 ]
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.200.5]
      routes:
      - to: 0.0.0.0/0
        via: 192.168.200.1
      mtu: 1500
  vlans:
    vlan60:
      id: 60
      link: eth0
      addresses:
      - 192.168.60.20/24
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.60.1]
      mtu: 1500
```

netplan.io on Ubuntu 20.04 has the fix where it properly generates the `/run/systemd/network/10-netplan-eth0.*` with a `[Match]` section having the crucial `Type=!vlan bond bridge` line present. My solution above simulates that with `OriginalName=enp1s0` to the same effect.